# Ruby on rails login error when installing Jackhammer

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I am trying to install Jackhammer vulnerability tool on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. More details of the tool can be found here https://github.com/olacabs/jackhammer and the user guide is https://jch.olacabs.com/userguide/

I am running Jackhammer locally using rails method, but i am not able to login using the default credentials i.e.,

**Username: jackhammer@olacabs.com
, password: j4ckh4mm3r**

I have done the DB installation and configured mysql as shown below.I have also taken care of all the gems and dependencies.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 25
  port: 3306
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: localhost
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: jackhammer_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: jackhammer_test
production:
  <<: *default
  database: jackhammer_production
```

After doing all the required installation i ran the command

```
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

also

```
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

separately but still same issue.

I have created databases in mysql as well.

```
mysql> show databases;
+------------------------+
| Database               |
+------------------------+
| information_schema     |
| jackhammer_development |
| jackhammer_production  |
| jackhammer_test        |
| mysql                  |
| performance_schema     |
| sys                    |
+------------------------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Then finally this,

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Puma 2.14.0 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
```

Now when i enter the default credentials or try to register i am not able to login, below is the **development.log** result..

```
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:16.824262 #5598]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-03 10:45:16 +0100
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:16.831569 #5598]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:16.831674 #5598]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"A/7MsxMp6f32zN2sbZKlTSCH23GYoYK+Wci24Lri1/a33EYOVUGYDq14Rkx2cL25iMb/6ff1BJRLKeMycQpe5Q==", "user"=>{"email"=>"jackhammer@olacabs.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"LOGIN"}
D, [2017-11-03T10:45:16.835452 #5598] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'jackhammer@olacabs.com'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:16.835800 #5598]  INFO -- : Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:16.836908 #5598]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:16.837000 #5598]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"A/7MsxMp6f32zN2sbZKlTSCH23GYoYK+Wci24Lri1/a33EYOVUGYDq14Rkx2cL25iMb/6ff1BJRLKeMycQpe5Q==", "user"=>{"email"=>"jackhammer@olacabs.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"LOGIN"}
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:16.980094 #5598]  INFO -- :   Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:17.477418 #5598]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 640ms (Views: 500.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
D, [2017-11-03T10:45:55.746744 #5598] DEBUG -- : 
D, [2017-11-03T10:45:55.746873 #5598] DEBUG -- : 
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:55.747045 #5598]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-03 10:45:55 +0100
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:55.780581 #5598]  INFO -- : Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
D, [2017-11-03T10:45:55.810327 #5598] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mTeam Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams`  ORDER BY `teams`.`name` ASC[0m
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:55.848704 #5598]  INFO -- :   Rendered users/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (55.1ms)
I, [2017-11-03T10:45:56.328669 #5598]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 548ms (Views: 542.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

I am really stuck and don't no how to proceed further. Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done so far is to only create the initial empty database (`rake db:migrate`).

You also need to run `rake db:seed` to load the seed data for the database:
https://github.com/olacabs/jackhammer/blob/master/web/app/db/seeds.rb

Comment: Thank you so much Casper, this really helped me a lot :-)